# Unverified breakpoint in VSCode in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My debug mode does not work as I see the unverified breakpoint notice in VSCode in debug mode.
I already checked the Launch json file and it is fine, but something else is wrong which I do not see what it is. Maybe something related to paths, etc.
I tried to make a new project in VSCode using the command and the new default Flutter project is OK.
So it seems like, if I can make a fresh project from my current project then my problem could be solved. But how? I tried to move my files from my current project to the newly made Default Flutter project but I do not think this is the way. Because I guess some of the files in my project are the source of issues...
I already deleted .vs file but no help.
Do you have any good idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First try cleaning the project files using `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`, try running the app without debugging and if you are down for making a new one just move the `lib` and `assets` folders and copy the content of `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Thx. I can execute the app but my break points do not work, so I cannot debug otherwise I can do whatever else. I did clean the project, it does not solve the issue. I prefer not to make another project if I can solve this debug mode issue, but if I do, you suggest to only copy these three files!? I have web folder, many changes in ios and android folder... so I do not think it is enough to just copy these 3 files.

Comment: Ok, you can try removing all the breakpoints and restart the app

Comment: No luck. I need to find a way to delete all VSCode/Flutter related files for debugging and then force VSCode to rewrite them. Because a new default project works with debugging. So still not solved! :(

Comment: Are you working with different git branches or maybe you opened the same project twice??

Answer (score 0):

On my step :

1. Close project, and make sure the folder/directory not accessed by another program
2. Rename directory
3. If you're working on git project, clone on the new folder
4. And happily run and debug your code again